# Trying to match SHA512 hashes between c# and nodejs crypto

Tags: c#, node.js, hash, cryptography, sha512

Given the following c# code.

```
    public static string HashSHA512( string phrase )
    {
        if( m_SHA512HashProvider == null )
            m_SHA512HashProvider = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();

        if ( m_HashBuffer == null )
            m_HashBuffer = new byte[512];

        int length = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( phrase, 0, phrase.Length > 512 ? 512 : phrase.Length, m_HashBuffer, 0 );
        byte[] hashed = m_SHA512HashProvider.ComputeHash( m_HashBuffer, 0, length );

        return BitConverter.ToString( hashed );         
    }
```

and the following nodejs code

```
  generate: function(input, cb){
    var hash = Crypto.createHash('sha512').update(input).digest('hex');
    console.log('crypto generate:', hash);
    return cb(hash);
  },
```

my hashes don't match up. How can I alter either side to make them match up accordingly?

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` is dangerous, it silently corrupts any character >127. Use UTF-8. For encoding `Encoding.Utf8` is okay, for decoding use `new UTF8Encoding(false, true)` so it throws on invalid data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your C# code.
Compare the following and try to figure out exactly where the faults are.

```
public static string HashSHA512( string phrase )
{
  if( m_SHA512HashProvider == null )
    m_SHA512HashProvider = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();

  byte[] hashed = m_SHA512HashProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase)); // or ASCII if that's sufficient for you input data.

  return BitConverter.ToString( hashed );         
}
```

Some hints:

- Use `UTF8` instead of `ASCII` (some characters might get truncated)
- [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't return a length of something. It returns an array of  bytes.
- [`ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e59xaaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have an `out` or `ref` parameter and since `m_HashBuffer` contains nothing, if `m_HashBuffer` is null, the hash is always computed on nothing.

**Edit**
Looking at the node.js API it seems that in C# you need to do an additional step:

```
return BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

This is because the `digest` method doesn't add the hyphens and all characters are lower case.

*Disclaimer: Code not tested.*

Comment: "some characters might get truncated" -- could you elaborate that please?

Comment: @zerkms characters that are out of the range of ASCII, such as accents, foreign languages, punctuation, symbols.

Comment: UTF16 is default for `String` type in .NET. If you use encoding `ASCII` then the conversion might screw things up. UTF8 is default for string storage to files. See [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/) for more information.

Comment: @Matthew: oh, I always thought it would just treat them as bytes. So I didn't expect any implicit conversion to perform

Comment: @zerkms: When converting from `string` to `byte[]` you cannot just `treat them as bytes`. You have to consider the encoding of the string.

Comment: If i could buy you a beer i would.

Comment: I think i figured out the problem, my scripts rehashing whats from my database.